# Laravel scope dynamic

Tags: laravel

I need to get logged user notifications by scope but it returns `App\User::notifications must return a relationship instance.`

## Code

`layout`

```
@auth
    @if(auth::user()->notifications > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <ul>
                @foreach (auth::user()->notifications as $notification)
                    <li>{{$notification->subject}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
        </div>
    @endif
@endauth
```

`User model`

```
public function notifications() {
  // return $this->hasMany(ProjectBroadcastApplicant::class);
  $notifications = ProjectBroadcastApplicant::where('user_id', $this->id)->get();
  return $notifications;
}
```

`ProjectBroadcastApplicant model`

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Where did I make mistake?!**

Answer (score 1):

Update your user Model:

```
public function notifications() {
    return $this->hasMany(ProjectBroadcastApplicant::class);
}
```

If you want to filter the notification for the user then you can add condition with the relationship definition.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

I've changed my user model to this

```
public function notifications() {
  return ProjectBroadcastApplicant::where('user_id', $this->id)->get();
}
```

and my blade from `@if(auth::user()->notifications > 0)` to `@if(auth::user()->notifications() > 0)`

now it's working.

Comment: Yes, you have changed the relationship to function so it will work